# Grails mockFor and How Best To Test The Method Is Called with Correct Arguments

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking

I want to test that the controller calls the service method with the correct arguments. What is the best way to do that?

My current plan is to use mockFor and then through the closure check the value passed in. Is there a better way to do the test through mockFor or the mocked object similar to what I can do with mockito to perform this same method call argument value test?

```
class HappyControllerTests extends ControllerUnitTestCase {
       :
    void testSomeValue() {
        def mockControl = mockFor(HappyService)
        def givenSomeItem = null
        mockControl.demand.serviceMethod(1..99) { String someItem -> givenSomeItem = someItem; }
        controller.happyService = mockControl.createMock() 

        controller.someAction()

        mockControl.verify()
        assertEquals("specific value", givenSomeItem)
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I like the answer from "Ted Naleid". Yet, IMHO large shops should use mockFor(..) See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/9.%20Testing.html#9.2 Integration Testing "...using these methods ensures that any changes you make to the given classes do not leak into other tests.."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I rarely use mockFor as I find groovy's built in metaClass stuff and `as ClassName` to be easier to work with and more powerful, I'd do this:

```
void testSomeValue() {
    def givenSomeItem = null
    controller.happyService = [
        serviceMethod: { String someItem -> givenSomeItem = someItem }
    ] as HappyService

    controller.someAction()
    assertEquals "specific value", givenSomeItem
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example. That was also my viewpoint until a few things happened: 1) I went to a great presentation by Jeff Brown and spoke with him. 2) In tests' setup(), I saw metaClass manipulated for all instances of a class sometimes and not properly restored.  This ended up causing side effect behavior across tests and I was the one who hunted down what was happening.  So.. Although it's possible just use Groovy metaClass for object mocks that one can inject and mockFor for the others, I recommend just using mockFor when in a big Java shop.

Comment: You normally hit the issue you're talking about if you change the metaClass on a Class.  If you're just modifying an instance (as in the example above), it's almost always safe and the changes will only live for as long as the instance lives.  The only time I hit an issue with this is when I mocked out an injected spring instance that was a singleton.  That same instance had been injected elsewhere so my changes weren't discarded after the test.   I don't completely disagree with you that mockFor could be better in a big Java shop though if people aren't very familiar with groovy.